# Mapbox on Android: Cancel onMapLongClick or Function When The Map Moves

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox

I have a map setup so a function is called when onMapLongClick is performed but the function also gets triggered when the map is pressed and moved and I want to make it so the function doesn't run if the map is moved while being pressed.

It looks like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
    //lng = point.getLongitude();
    //lat = point.getLatitude();
    getResults(point);
}
```

MapBox has a listener for map movement and there is also the onTouchEvent for android but how can either be used to prevent the function from running when the map is moved? or what would be a better approach?

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this which might not be the best way but it's working.

1. I declared a variable boolean mapMoved = false;
2. added MapBox's onMove events (onMoveBeing, onMove, onMoveEnd) and set the variable to true whenever it moved and to false at the end of movement.
3. set a condition within the onMapLongClick to return false is the map moved or else it executes the function.

   ```
   @Override
    public boolean onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
        if(mapMoved){
            return false;
        }else{
            getResults(point);
            return true;
        }
    }
   ```

I am not certain if this is the best approach but so far it's working as intended.